# How long does it take to install chromadb on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, chromadb

I have developed a django project and am trying to deploy to AWS EC2 Instance.
My project uses chromadb so I try to install with this command.

```
pip install chromadb
```

Then it installs all the related dependencies but when it starts to install hnswlib, it freezes.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: hnswlib
Building wheel for hnswlib (pyproject.toml) ... \
```

It doesn't give any error but no progress.
How to handle this?
Should I wait? This was the second time for me to deploy this kind of project but at the first time, I installed chromadb without any issue.
But at that time, I used the Instance that my client has provided. Now I created the Instance with myself.
Are there any kind of settings about Instance?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for this:

---

### **BUT FIRST!!!**

*You could wait for some time to see if it eventually completes.*

*Anyways*, this sounds like there might be version conflicts between `hnswlib` and other packages in your project, causing the installation to hang.

Check if there are any package requirements for `hnswlib` and make sure they are compatible with other packages in your Django project.

---

### **If that doesn't work:**

Sometimes, specific settings, such as security groups, firewall rules, or DNS configurations, can cause issues and break package installs.

Check if the instance has the correct permissions and network configurations.